# How do I beat Galactus?

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

I've managed to get to the final boss in offline mode pretty easily, but Galactus is just kicking my butt.  I don't even quite know if my attacks are doing damage at all, and he usually wipes me out in 1-2 hits.  Since he isn't like a standard fight (as he's HUGE),  the usual tricks doesn't that well on him.  What are some common strategies I should be looking out for when fighting him?

Comment: Is this question platform specific?

Comment: @JohnoBoy I don't know enough about the version on other systems to say otherwise.  I'd imagine the controls and such may have been reworked for the vita.  If you know more feel free to remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IGN has a section in their wiki about how to defeat Galactus, as well as a video. These ideas seem kind of simple, but apparently this is a strategy that works, even on very hard.

http://www.ign.com/wikis/ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3/Galactus

Comment: yea, I eventually figured out that some of those moves I can't dodge and just have to block it out